# string.format issue in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
 var amount="0";
 @String.Format("{0:0.00}", amount)
```

returns `"0"`

While I was expecting it to return

```
"0.00"
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that var has explicitly typed amount as a string, get rid of the quotes.

Comment: You are printing the string "0". Its representation is "0", try printing decimal amount = 0;

Comment: why is this question being up-voted?  it's a simple programming mistake. ho-hum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Formatting a string will just return the string itself, you have to format a number to get it formatted as a number:

```
var amount = 0;
```

---

A variable with implicit type which is assigned an integer value will be an integer, so it won't have a fractional part. You might want to specify the type:

```
double amount = 0;
```

Or use a double value:

```
var amount = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String.Format("{0:#.##}", amount)
```

OR

```
String.Format("{0:N2}", amount)
```

---

Scratch this - Guffa's answer is correct...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.ToString("N2")
```

It will use the CultureInfo to format the number. This means that your thousands separator might be different depending on the used CultureInfo. You can also pass the desired CultureInfo if you want.